# How to call JavaScript from the address bar?

Tags: javascript, syntax

This script should work:

```
javascript:alert('b');
```

It works in Opera for me, but doesn't work in Firefox..
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Surely it would have been quicker to try both of those than post a question? :D

Comment: I did. I'm putting following into an address bar: javascript:alert(2+2); but it does not alert, though it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`javascript:alert('b');` would be enough.*

---

**Update**: new versions of Firefox don't give you access to `window` and thus - to `window.alert()` from javascript:urls typed in address bar. Use `throw 'sometext'`, and see the result in console (yes, as an error). That's the only output you can have now.

Comment: firefox. alert('b') just allerts letter 'b'. That's a test of proper syntax before I can write some more serious stuff.

Comment: new versions of Firefox don't give you access to `alert()` from typed javascript:urls. Use `throw b`, and see the result in console. That's the only output you can have now..